# API to create iOS Photostream album

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6, icloud, alassetslibrary

We have a photo capture application. We want to share the captured photos using 
photostream from our application.
From iOS 6 , Photos app supports photo stream share. I didnt find any API to support this.

I have following queries regarding photostream-

> 1. Is thre any API to create photostream album?
> 2. API to add photos to photostream.
> 3. API to share photostream album.

Can any one help me to find the soultion for these queries.

Comment: I can't find anything on this either. Must not be public yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you can only show the contents of a PhotoStream album using AssetsLibrary. You can't create or add photos to a PhotoStream-Album. If you want that feature, please fill a request at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was unable to understand your response. Is it possible to create or add photos a PhotoStream-Album?

Comment: sorry..there was a typo. Corrected that.